# Metrics from multiple threads

Tags: java, concurrency, metrics

So this seems like a pretty common use case, and maybe I'm over thinking it, but I'm having an issue with keeping centralized metrics from multiple threads.  Say I have multiple worker threads all processing records and I every 1000 records I want to spit out some metric.  Now I could have each thread log individual metrics, but then to get throughput numbers, but I'd have to add them up manually (and of course time boundaries won't be exact).  Here's a simple examples:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

   private static int count = 0;
   private static long processingTime = 0;

   public void run() {
       while (true) {
          ...get record
          count++;
          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
          ...do work
          long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
          processingTime += (end-start);
          if (count % 1000 == 0) {
              ... log some metrics
              processingTime = 0;
              count = 0;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Hope that makes some sense.  Also I know the two static variables will probably be AtomicInteger and AtomicLong . . . but maybe not.  Interested in what kinds of ideas people have.  I had thought about using Atomic variables and using a ReeantrantReadWriteLock - but I really don't want the metrics to stop the processing flow (i.e. the metrics should have very very minimal impact on the processing).  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offloading the actual processing to another thread can be a good idea. The idea is to encapsulate your data and hand it off to a processing thread quickly so you minimize impact on the threads that are doing meaningful work.

There is a small handoff contention, but that cost is usually a lot smaller than any other type of synchronization that it should be a good candidate in many situations. I think M. Jessup's solution is pretty close to mine, but hopefully the following code illustrates the point clearly.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

   private static final Metrics metrics = new Metrics();

   public void run() {
      while (true) {
        ...get record
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ...do work
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // process the metric asynchronously
        metrics.addMetric(end - start);
     }
  }

  private static final class Metrics {
     // a single "background" thread that actually handles
     // processing
     private final ExecutorService metricThread = 
           Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
     // data (no synchronization needed)
     private int count = 0;
     private long processingTime = 0;

     public void addMetric(final long time) {
        metricThread.execute(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              count++;
              processingTime += time;
              if (count % 1000 == 0) {
                 ... log some metrics
                 processingTime = 0;
                 count = 0;
              }
           }
        });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I always wonder about solutions like this.  Because are actually achieving what you want?  That is, would the cost of thread preemption from the OS to allow this logging  reduce the amount of metrics the other working threads are achieving (that is only a valid question if number_of_working_threads > cores_on_machine).  Instead of doing it on the same thread after you have already gained the metrics.

Comment: True, this works best under certain conditions. I would slightly modify your condition to number_of_CPU_busy_threads > cores_on_machine. In reality, a lot of threads spend majority of their processing time in an idle state (blocked for I/O, etc.). The number of truly active threads would not outnumber the number of cores in most situations, otherwise you're actually outstripping CPU capacity anyway. This pattern works well also if the action is "serializing" in its nature (e.g. logging to file comes to mind).

Comment: I really like this answer - can't say how it will effect processing time off the bat but my guess is the metrics thread will be kept pretty busy without actually effecting the running record processors.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest if you don't want the logging to interfere with the processing, you should have a separate log worker thread and have your processing threads simply provide some type of value object that can be handed off. In the example I choose a LinkedBlockingQueue since it has the ability to block for an insignificant amount of time using offer() and you can defer the blocking to another thread that pulls the values from a queue. You might need to have increased logic in the MetricProcessor to order data, etc depending on your requirements, but even if it is a long running operation it wont keep the VM thread scheduler from restarting the real processing threads in the mean time.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      ... do some stuff
      if (count % 1000 == 0) {
        ... log some metrics
        if(MetricProcessor.getInstance().addMetrics(
            new Metrics(processingTime, count, ...)) {
          processingTime = 0;
          count = 0;
        } else {
          //the call would have blocked for a more significant
          //amount of time, here the results
          //could be abandoned or just held and attempted again
          //as a larger data set later
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public class WorkerMetrics {
  ...some interesting data
  public WorkerMetrics(... data){
    ...
  }
  ...getter setters etc
}

public class MetricProcessor implements Runnable {
  LinkedBlockingQueue metrics = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
  public boolean addMetrics(WorkerMetrics m) {
    return metrics.offer(m); //This may block, but not for a significant amount of time.
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      WorkMetrics m = metrics.take(); //wait here for something to come in
      //the above call does all the significant blocking without
      //interrupting the real processing
      ...do some actual logging, aggregation, etc of the metrics
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue definitely blocks on add.  Are you thinking ConcurrentLinkedQueue?  drainTo also will block. The case to add a thread circumvents the original problem, no matter what you do you will have some sort of serialization with multithreading.  No use to add another thread in my opinion.

Comment: Yes it blocks on offer, however the amount of time it blocks is trivial in comparison with any time that it might block if it were doing the full metrics logging. Op made the statement "but I really don't want the metrics to stop the processing flow", so here we delegate to allow the processing flow to continue. And sure drainTo blocks, but if that is in the Metrics processing it doesn't matter, since its separated from the main processing. If you don't have another thread how do you serialize without blocking one or more of the processing threads for a potentially extended period of time?

Comment: If there is substantial amount of work done for logging the metrics you can make the argument to do it in another thread.  But you should update your answer and remove statements that the add, offer and take will not block.  That doesn't help the OP because its not factual.

Comment: Point taken, answer updated to make it more clear that offer may block briefly.

Comment: Essentially I think this is the same as the top answer - in the background the Executor service uses BlockingQueue's very similar to this - but hides some of the complexity under the hood.  A Good answer, but I think the other one is slightly more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you depend on the state of count and the state of processingTime to be in synch then you would have to be using a Lock.  For example if when `++count % 1000 == 0` is true, you want to evaluate the metrics of processingTime at THAT time.

For that case, it would make sense to use a ReentrantLock.  I wouldn't use a RRWL because there isn't really an instance where a pure read is occuring.  It is always a read/write set.  But you would need to Lock around all of

```
  count++
  processingTime += (end-start);
  if (count % 1000 == 0) {
      ... log some metrics
      processingTime = 0;
      count = 0;
  }
```

Whether or not count++ is going to be at that location, you will need to lock around that also.
Finally if you are using a Lock, you do not need an AtomicLong and AtomicInteger.  It just adds to the overhead and isn't more thread-safe.

Comment: I believe I said that in the actual question.

Comment: When you wrote, 'but maybe not' I thought you meant you would take the concurrency hit by not using AtomicLong :)